# How to remove Magento2 sample data without uninstall

Tags: magento2, sample-data, uninstall

Is there a way to remove sample data in Magento2 without uninstalling/re-installing Magento?

I want this because I changed settings in my backend that I don't want to be removed.

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 8):

`bin/magento sampledata:remove` to completely remove sample data. `bin/magento sampledata:reset` is used to update sample data before updating Magento application.

+1 for taking backup before doing so. `bin/magento setup:backup --db` creates a backup for the database.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html

Comment: it remove only product images nothing else

Comment: how can remove default products ?

Answer (score 4):

run this in the console `bin/magento sampledata:reset`.
And backup your db in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Sir it gives me an error `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch` after running the above command

Answer (score 0):

Use this command on command line:

```
bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

For More Detail use this : 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html